# SQL how to get select attribute that is array by join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am using postgresql. How to get from first table to second? Thank you

```
 id  | type | sum         
-----+------+-----
 1   | a    | 100
 2   | a    | 200
 3   | b    | 500


 t_sum | type | history          
-------+------+---------------
 300   | a    | ['id' => 1, 'sum' => 100], ['id' => 2, 'sum' => 200]
 500   | b    | ['id' => 3, 'sum' => 500]
```

I tried this, no results:

`SELECT DISTINCT(a.type), SUM(a.sum) as t_sum, b.* as history FROM mytable a LEFT JOIN mytable b ON a.id = b.id GROUP BY a.type`

Comment: `DISTINCT`  is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` - and works in the whole selected rows. Not needed anyway since the GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution returns the last column as a `json` array:

```
SELECT sum(sum) AS t_sum,
       type,
       array_to_json(
          array_agg(
             json_build_object('id', id, 'sum', sum)
          )
       ) history
FROM history
GROUP BY type
ORDER BY type;

┌───────┬──────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ t_sum │ type │                      history                      │
├───────┼──────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│   300 │ a    │ [{"id" : 1, "sum" : 100},{"id" : 2, "sum" : 200}] │
│   500 │ b    │ [{"id" : 3, "sum" : 500}]                         │
└───────┴──────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, I just checked this on Postgres and it works.

Comment: Thank you. Why simple array not working, only json format? I am using php.

Comment: Sure, you can use a simple array, this is just an example. But what data type should `['id' => 1, 'sum' => 100]` be in that case?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what datatypes Postgresql returns. I guess simple array like `Array([1] => ['id' => 1, 'sum' => 100], [2] => ['id' => 2, 'sum' => 200])`

Comment: Yes, but what is the `['id' => 1, 'sum' => 100]`? A string? A [hstore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) value? I decided to go for JSON, but if you tell me what you need, I can adapt the answer.

Comment: When I do `SELECT * FROM table` what format Postgresql returns? I need the same :-)

Comment: I see we make no progress here. Maybe you should think of what you intend to do with the `history` column in your program.